# Why can't the behavior of len() be changed even after modifying __len__(self)?

Tags: python-3.x, function, methods

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, pay):
        self.pay = pay

    def __len__(self):
        return "{}".format(len(str(self.pay)))

worker1 = Worker(1000)

print(worker1.__len__())
print(len(worker1))
```

```
/home/minmin/PycharmProjects/myproject/venv/bin/python /home/minmin/PycharmProjects/myproject/mro.py
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/minmin/PycharmProjects/myproject/mro.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(len(worker1))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I print calling the dunder method (`worker1.__len__()`) it returns 4 in the console. But when I try to use print  the `len(worker1)` function using the same instance (`worker1`) it throws an error. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in function `len` is a wrapper function that calls the `__len__` method of the given object and then validates that the returning value of the `__len__` method is an integer. If you call the `__len__` method directly, then no such validation is done.

In other words, you should always make sure that `__len__` returns an integer to pass `len`'s validation:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(str(self.pay))
```